# WSO2 IS 5.10.0 - Add new language in User Portal Overview

Tags: configuration, wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I log in "user-portal" of WSO2 Identity Server (the url is "https://localhost:9443/user-portal/overview"), I can see four options to change the language (english, portuguese, sinhalese or tamil).

I need to add more options in this section. How can I do this? I can't see a "Resource.properties" inside the folder "/repository/deployment/server/webapps/user-portal" to do something like in the following link https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/localization-support-in-identity-server/#localization-support-in-identity-server.

Thanks in advance.

Gonzalo.

Comment: FYI, the user portal will partially reflect the browser language as well ie only some sections in the user-portal will get translated with respect to browser language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2IS UserPortal is a React-based application and in there what is done is to combine all the configurations in i118 to react config mappings if you want to change anything you need to do it at the code level.

https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/v1.0.72/apps/user-portal/src/configs/i18n.ts

you can map all the configs to your preferred language and map them to the configurations used in UserPortal by building the package.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!!! I modified the source code of the "user-portal" and I was able to replace that compiled code on the server.

Comment: @GonzaloColinoAlonso hey bro, do you have any ideas about my question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787981/unable-to-deploy-user-portal-from-identity-apps-tag-1-0-72